# AWS Congito User singup timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a cognito user...

```js
function createCognitoUser(id, event) {
    const { user: { email, name,  password, first_name, last_name } } = event.arguments;
    const params = {
        Username: email,
        Password: password,
        ClientId: process.env.DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID,
        UserAttributes: [{
                Name: 'name',
                Value: name || `${last_name},${first_name}`
            },
            {
                Name: 'email',
                Value: email
            },
            {
                Name: 'custom:tenant_id',
                Value: id
            }
            /* more items */
        ]
    };
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('initiating cognito user creation for ', params);
        cognitoserviceprovider.signUp(params, function(error, data) {
            console.log('cognito user created for', params);
            if (error) {
                console.error(`Failed to create Cognito User \n`, error);
                 switch (error.code) {
                    case 'UsernameExistsException':
                        return reject(errorList.EMAILID_EXISTS);
                    default:
                        return reject(error);
                }
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Earlier it used to work, but now it is getting timeout. not sure why.
`cognito.adminCreateUser` is working without any issue. Timeout is 6sec. I;ve tried increasing to 2 mins, and even then it fails.

Comment: Where do you call `createCognitoUser`?

Comment: it a almbda function. Code is correct. Issue was related to ip address. Changing the lambda's name worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is correct. Issue was related to ip address. Changing the lambda's name worked.